# How can I debug a DependencyInjection in a bundle ?

Tags: symfony

I want to know if all my services and variables are correctly set. In this bundle I dont have any access to bin/console and the symfony version is 2.8.
Is there a way to get one ? I want to do something like `bin/console debug:container` or just run the app to see if there is any errors.

Comment: Most of the time I cheat and just wrap the bundle inside of an app.  But if you want to do it right then look at the mailer bundle or maybe the security bundle to see how to write tests for your dependency injection stuff.  It can be a bit involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have a shared host and do no access to cli on the server.

If so, you may go with CoreSphere Console bundle, a cli simulator inside browser window.

check its github for installation and usage:

https://github.com/CoreSphere/ConsoleBundle

[image: CoreSphere ConsoleBundle]

Comment: No, I don't have AppKernel on this bundle, it should be an independant bundle that is using only doctrine.

Comment: If so, please edit your question and describe your access rights in detail